# Windows batch: delayed expansion in a for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to modify a few specific lines of numbers of text files, and I wrote a batch file as follows:

```
@echo off
set n=0
set n1=10
set n2=40
cd.>output.txt

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n .* test.txt') do (
set "var=%%i"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a n=!n!+1
echo.!n!
set var=!var:*:=!
rem if !n!=%n1% ...
rem if !n!=%n2% ...
(echo.!var!)>>output.txt
endlocal
)
start output.txt
```

However, this doesn't work as expected.
After some tests, I think the `!n!` expansion is not normally delayed. That is very strange, because `!var!` expansion is normally delayed.

By the way, the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and `endlocal` commands are put in the `for` loop, because otherwise the special character `!` will be abandoned.

Comment: Your chance of getting help will greatly improve if you explain what you are trying to do as well as what exactly isn't working. For the part that isn't working you should explain the expected result and describe what you are seeing.

Comment: I didn't try to analyze your code, but shouldn't you be using `set /a n+=1` instead of `set /a n=!n!+1`

Comment: @panda-34 - I prefer your suggested syntax, but both should work.

Comment: But the delayed variant can only work inside the `setlocal/endlocal` block and there the variable `n` can't really be increased

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the problem what you see is that `n` will never increase.

But that isn't a problem of the delayed expansion, it's an effefct of the `setlocal/endlocal` block inside the loop.
As @panda-34 mentioned you should use the extended syntax of `set/a` and move the statement outside the `setlocal/endlocal` block.

```
@echo off
set n=0
set n1=10
set n2=40

(
  for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n .* test.txt') do (
    set "var=%%i"
    set /a n+=1
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo !n!
    set var=!var:*:=!
    rem if !n!=%n1% ...
    rem if !n!=%n2% ...
    (echo(!var!)
    endlocal
  )
) >output.txt
start output.txt
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is just as you said, but your codes does not work.

Comment: @user1446072 - As I implied in my previous question comment: It's very difficult for anyone to "fix" your code if we have no idea what it is supposed to do. It was a good catch on jeb's part to find one significant problem (+1), but the expected behavior of your code remains a mystery.

Comment: After some modification, the problem has been solved. The key is to move the statement `set /a` outside the `setlocal/endlocal` block. Thank you!

Comment: @dbenham: I am sorry i did not state the problem clearly. I am a newbie to windows batch and this forum, and, my English is not very good... Anyway, thank you all!